# I want to Add the value of two or more textboxes

Tags: c#

So I want to make a program where I can plus the value in two or more text boxes together.
You can see on the [picture](https://gyazo.com/75ce4944aa70029e53e92f288a5adb2f)  I want to plus spm1 and spm2 together, and make the value show under >points

Any help is appreciated!

```
private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text.ToString());
    Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text.ToString());
    sum = txtspm2.Text+txtspm1.Text;
    lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the problem? Where's your code? Also, please don't include links to images in your post. Add an actual image.

Comment: your link is not working..page not found error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
 Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text.ToString());
            
Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text.ToString());
            
sum = txtspm2.Text+txtspm1.Text;
            
lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();

i tried this but this just added the nubers like if i put the numbers 2 and 4 then hit the button i just got 42

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I think new users can't add images

Comment: In addition to all of the things everyone else has pointed out, I'd like to add you don't need `.ToString();` at the end of `someTextBox.Text`. The `Text` property already IS a `string`. So you're converting a `string` to a `string`. It's redundant, unnecessary, and makes the code less easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

> private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text.ToString()); Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text.ToString()); sum = txtspm2.Text+txtspm1.Text; lblsum.Text = sum.ToString(); i tried this but this just added the nubers like if i put the numbers 2 and 4 then hit the button i just got 42

Your problem is that `+` operator behaves different from string and integers, in your case. try this instead

```
var n1= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text); 
var n2= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text;
sum =n1+n2; 
lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

`+` in string concatenates thats why you get that result

Answer (score 4):

```
sum = txtspm2.Text+txtspm1.Text
```

.Text returns a string value, so this is concatenating two strings, not adding two integers.  Convert the values to integers, then add them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the sum of all the numbers entered in textboxes then you can just give a common class name to all those textboxes and then

on textbox change event write this code in Jquery

```
var value=$('.txtClass').val();
$('#total').text(value);
```

Just saw your updated question although usually jquery is used for the given scenario but since you need it on server side so you can simply do this

```
    int val1= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text); 
    int val2= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text);
    lblsum.Text = (val1+val2).ToString();
```

Comment: @bto.rdz As I have mentioned in my answer that this prblem is usually solved using jquery but if the op wants to use C# then I have also provided the C# code..

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
    var n1= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm1.Text); 
    var n2= Convert.ToInt32(txtspm2.Text);
    lblsum.Text = (n1+n2).ToString(); 
   }
```